# Cloned and forked a repo to use locally. When I npm install, I get an error: could not read from a remote repository

Tags: git, github

I've cloned + forked a public repo and tried to npm install the dependencies. When I do, I get this error: `npm ERR! ERROR: Repository not found.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.`

I've already setup the SSH key, added it to my GitHub, but still get the same error when I npm install. Any advice/things to try?

Comment: Is this referencing your own project or some dependency? Have you modified your `package.json` to point to your fork?

Comment: A public project. I found someone say that when you have a repo as a dependency, reformat the depency to be the https url of that repo, but that did not solve the issue I have.